# How to replace fields using substr comparison

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I have two files where I need to fetch the last 6 char of  Field-11 from F1 and lookup on F2, if it match I need to replace Field-9 of F1 with  Field-1 and Filed-2 of F2.

file1:

```
12345||||||756432101000||756432||756432101000||  
aaaaa||||||986754812345||986754||986754812345||  
ccccc||||||134567222222||134567||134567222222||
```

file2:

```
101000|AAAA   
812345|20030
```

The expected output is:

```
12345||||||756432101000||101000AAAA ||756432101000||  
aaaaa||||||986754812345||81234520030||986754812345||  
ccccc||||||134567222222||134567||134567222222||
```

I have tried:

```
awk -F '|' -v OFS='|' 'NR==FNR{a[$1,$2];next}  {b=substr($11,length($11)-7)}  b in a {$9=a[$1,$2]}1'
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd write it this way as a full script in a file, rather than a one-liner:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f                                                                                                       

BEGIN {
    FS = "|";
    OFS = FS;
}

NR == FNR { # second file: the replacements to use
    map[$1] = $2
    next;
}

{ # first file specified: the main file to manipulate
    b = substr($11,length($11)-5);
    if (map[b]) {
        $9 = b map[b]
    }
    print
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -F '|' -v OFS='|' 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next} {b=substr($11,length($11)-5)} b in a {$9=b a[b]}1' file2 file1
12345||||||756432101000||101000AAAA||756432101000||
aaaaa||||||986754812345||81234520030||986754812345||
ccccc||||||134567222222||134567||134567222222||
```

#### How it works

awk implicitly loops through every line in both files, starting with `file2` because it is specified first on the command line.

- `-F '|'`

  This tells awk to use `|` as the field separator on input
- `-v OFS='|'`

  This tells awk to use `|` as the field separator on output
- `NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}`

  While reading the first file, `file2`, this saves the second field, `$2`, as the value of associative array `a` with the first field, `$1`, as the key.

  `next` tells awk to skip the rest of the commands and start over on the next line.
- `b=substr($11,length($11)-5)`

  This extracts the last six characters of field 11 and saves them in variable `b`.
- `b in a {$9=b a[b]}`

  This tests to see if `b` is one of the keys of associative array `a`.  If it is, this assigns the ninth field, `$9`, to the combination of `b` and `a[b]`.
- `1`

  This is awk's cryptic shorthand for print-the-line.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion

Comment: Excellent explanations

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there:

```
$ awk -F '|' -v OFS='|' 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next} {b=substr($11,length($11)-5)}  b in a {$9=b a[b]}1' file2 file1
12345||||||756432101000||101000AAAA   ||756432101000||  
aaaaa||||||986754812345||81234520030||986754812345||  
ccccc||||||134567222222||134567||134567222222||
$
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion